# Cant Install Bs4 Faker

Tags: python

I downloaded Python And in cmd I´m trying to get the bs4 Faker. Im sure I´m typing it correctly.

```
pip install bs4 Faker
Collecting bs4
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bs4 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for bs4

Help?

Comment: It's `beautifulsoup4` not `bs4`... Once installed - you refer to it as `bs4` for imports though...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) comment, run:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

instead of:

```
pip install bs4
```